# How to convert an arbitrary object to String with EL + JSTL? (calling toString())

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

Is there any way to call toString() on an object with the EL and JSTL? (I need the String representation of an enum as index in a map in a JSP EL expression.) I hoped something like `${''+object}` would work like in java, but EL isn't that nice, and there does not seem to be any function that does it.

Clarification: I have a variable `somemap` that maps Strings to Strings, and I have a variable `someenum` that is an enumeration. I'd like to do something like `${somemap[someenum.toString()]}`. (Of course .toString() does not work, but what does?)

Comment: I fixed "JSTL" in your question to "EL". The `${}` things are not JSTL. It is Expression Language (EL). JSTL is the standard taglib, e.g. `c:out`, `c:forEach`, etc.

Comment: It really is EL + JSTL - the solution does not work with EL alone but both.

Comment: Your **actual problem** is with EL, not with JSTL. JSTL is just a dumb flow control taglib which knows absolutely nothing about expressions and backend data like enums.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55136138/2465785, the `${'' + object}` is not valid, but you can use `${''}${object}`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You just do it like this:

```
${object}
```

And it'll `toString` it for you.

---

**edit**: Your nested expression can be resolved like this:

```
<c:set var="myValue">${someenum}</c:set>
${somemap[myValue]}
```

The first line stringifies (using `toString()`) the `${someenum}` expression and stores it in the `myValue` variable. The second line uses `myValue` to index the map.

Comment: Right, but I can't use this inside in an EL expression. See my clarification; ${somemap[${someenum}]} is not allowed.

Comment: <c:set var="myValue">${someenum}</c:set>  works here because the value is within the Body of the c:set tag, so the value has to get toString()'d. Note that if you did <c:set var="myValue" value="${someenum}"/> then it will retain it's type (enum) and not get converted to a String.

Comment: @Hans-PeterStörr right, that is not valid syntax... you can't have ${} within another ${} expression, and you don't need to. It would just be ${somemap[someenum]}. However, since you want someenum to be converted to String, you can't do it this way in one-line, you have to convert it first. <c:set var="someEnumString">${somenum}</c:set> then ${somemap[someEnumString]}

Answer (score 6):

Couple things you can do.

One, you can use c:set -

```
<c:set var="nowAString">${yourVar}</c:set>
```

Another thing you can do is create your own EL function, call it toString, and then call that in JSTL. EL functions are basically static methods hooked up with a taglib file. Straightforward to do.

Edit:

Really? Did you actually, you know, try it?

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <%
        pageContext.setAttribute("testDate", new java.util.Date());
        %>

        <c:set var="myVar">${testDate}</c:set>
        testDate = ${testDate}<br/>
        myVar = ${myVar}<br/>
        testDate Class = ${testDate.class}<br/>
        myVar Class = ${myVar.class}<br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

And JSP 2.0 tagfile and JSTL functions are trivial.

Comment: Note that is important to use the body, not the value attribute if you are trying to use c:set to do toString().
If x is an Integer...
<c:set var="foo" value="${x}"/> foo will still be an Integer
<c:set var="foo">${x}</c:set> foo will be a String

Answer (score 3):

I think in new versions of JSP api you can call methods, even with parameters!

I just tried `${statusColorMap[jobExecution.exitStatus.toString()]}` and it works fine!

Comment: I'm using EL to write JXLS Template. And `toString` method save my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Will Hartung should work. Here's a copy'n'paste'n'runnable [SSCCE](http://sscce.org):

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!doctype html>

<%!
    enum MyEnum {
        FOO, BAR
    }
%>
<%
    request.setAttribute("myEnum", MyEnum.FOO);
    java.util.Map<String, String> map = new java.util.HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("FOO", "value of key FOO");
    map.put("BAR", "value of key BAR");
    request.setAttribute("map", map);
%>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Map: ${map}
        <p>Enum: ${myEnum}
        <c:set var="myEnumAsString">${myEnum}</c:set>
        <p>Map value: ${map[myEnumAsString]}        
    </body>
</html>
```

This yields:

> Map: {BAR=value of key BAR, FOO=value of key FOO}
>
> Enum: FOO
>
> Map value: value of key FOO

*(scriptlets are just for quick prototyping, don't use them in real!)*

Answer (score 0):

```
//In java

public class Foo {
    // Define properties and get/set methods
    private int prop1;
    private String prop2;



    public String toString() {
        String jsonString = ...; /// Convert this object to JSON string
        return jsonString;
    }
}
```

As [skaffman said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2883779/419348), EL syntax `${obj}` will call `toString()`.

So, if a object `foo` in `JSTL` is an instance of `Foo`.
Then,

```
// test.jsp

<script>
    var a = ${foo};  // ${foo} will be {"prop1": ooo, "prop2": "xxx"}
    console.log(a.prop1);
    console.log(a.prop2);
</script>
```

---

### Example

If `toString()` will output `JSON` format string, for example, `Foo`'s `toString()` outputs `JSON` format string. then:

```
// .java codes
Foo a = ...// a Foo object. => { 'prop1': ooo }
List<Foo> b = ... //< Array. => [ {'prop1': ooo}, {prop1: xxx} ]

// Pass object to JSTL by HttpServletRequest or ..
request.setAttribute('a', a);
request.setAttribute('b', b);

// .jsp codes
<span>${a.prop1}</span>

<script>
    var aa = ${a}; // ${a} => { 'prop1': ooo }
    var bb = ${b}; // ${b} => [ {'prop1': ooo}, {prop1: xxx} ]

    console.log(aa.prop1);
    console.log(bb[0].prop1);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

ugly but simple enough

```
<someTag someValue="${yourObject}${''}" ... />
```

for example, someValue only accept strings (but declare as java.lang.Object), this way enforce it with string concatenation