# The method replace(String, String, String) in the type Functions is not applicable for the arguments (StringBuffer, String, String)

Tags: java, jstl

Here is my jsp file:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/plain" %>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%><%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' prefix='c'%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<c:out value="${fn:replace(pageContext.request.requestURL, pageContext.request.requestURI, '')}" /><c:out value="${model.uri}" />
```

I am getting the error

```
The method replace(String, String, String) in the type Functions is not applicable for the arguments (StringBuffer, String, String)
```

I have tried pageContext.request.requestURL.toString() but toString() is apparently not a method. Any suggestions?

Comment: This problem does by the way not occur on my environment. It executes perfectly fine. I'm using JSTL 1.2. Are you using JSTL 1.1? For download links, check our JSTL info page http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: Yes I am using 1.1, I might have to look at upgrading.

Comment: You can also try surrounding it with String.toString(...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`StringBuffer#toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#toString%28%29) is definitely the right method to call. The problem is calling it using EL. You can convert it to string using `<c:set>` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883726/how-to-convert-an-arbitrary-object-to-string-with-el-jstl-calling-tostring).

```
<c:set var="url">${pageContext.request.requestURL}</c:set>
<c:out value="${fn:replace(url, pageContext.request.requestURI, '')}" />
```

That said, I think there's a better way to get the output string you want that doesn't use `fn:replace`.

Comment: Hm, that `<c:set>` line was not there when I typed in my answer.

Comment: @BalusC would you believe that I didn't take it from your answer, but from skaffman's (the one I linked)?

Comment: +1. @BalusC, I was gonna +1 you too but you deleted your answer.

Comment: @Asaph: I don't like duplicate answers. Matt edited the right answer in within the grace period, so I deleted mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
pageContext.request.requestURL.toString()
```

Should work.

Answer (score -1):

try `"" + pageContext.request.requestURL` instead of `pageContext.request.requestURL.toString()`